# Programmatically changing html select element not triggers events

Tags: javascript, html

On the [Yahoo weather website](https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/united-kingdom/london/london-44418), there is a select element which could be retrieved by:

```
let sel = document.querySelector('select');
```

You can manually select different options (Temperature, Wind, and Precipitation) and see the next 24-hour forecast for each one. The problem is that when you change the option programmatically (as below), although the selected option changes, the onChange event not triggers (i.e., forecasts not update):

```
sel.selectedIndex = 1;
```

`sel.selectedIndex = 2;`

I've tested different solutions prepared on similar threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript/28324400) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291445/how-to-set-value-to-select-box-and-trigger-change-event/43291695)), but unfortunately non of them works. Any helps would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: `change()` event is not triggered automatically, you need to trigger it, as `sel.change();` after setting the `selectedIndex`

Comment: Either calling `sel.change()` or `sel.onchange()` returns this error: **Uncaught TypeError: sel.onchange is not a function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use below code:-

```
const sel = document.querySelector('select');
sel.value = 'precipitation'; // You can change this value to whatever you want
sel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {'view': window,'bubbles': true}));
```

Comment: That sounds greate! Thank you @Diwakar Singh. That worked for me. Would you please explain the last line a bit more?

Comment: I was trying this for the last 15 mins, I was just missing the `bubbles: true` setting, my bad. And I guess `view: window` is not required.